# how to display backend data (variable) to frontend page

Tags: sql, yii2

I want to display the count of rows of each table in Database.
I have created a view for that in frontend

file path :..\frontend\views\site\home.php

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <h3>i want here $no_of_rows</h3>
  <h5>Companies</h5>
  </div>
```

And all tables is in backend folder

file path: ..\backend\controllers\CompaniesController.php

```
$no_of_rows = Companies::find()->count();
```

using that I get the no of rows... but I want to display it on the frontend. how to display the value of backend variable in frontend?

Comment: You should have controller in frontend to display value in frontend

Comment: frontend/controllers/sitecontroller.php                                                 
  public function actionHome()
    {                                                                                                       
    return $this->render('home');
    } I have used above code in frontend controller.

Comment: add `use backend\models\Companies` where you want to access backend model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SiteController`:

```
use app\backend\models\Companies;

...

public function actionHome()
{
   ...
   $no_of_rows = Companies::find()->count();
   $this->render('home', ['no_of_rows' => $no_of_rows]);
}
```

Comment: Class 'app\backend\models\Companies' not found

Comment: So where is your Companies model class placed?

Comment: backend\model\Companies

Comment: Ok. Change `use app\backend\models\Companies;`to `use app\backend\model\Companies;`

Comment: Companies model class placed in app\backend\models\Companies

Comment: Check namespace and class name if you still have 'Class not found' error

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="col-md-2">
 <h3>
     i want here <?php echo $no_of_rows ?>
 </h3> 
<h5>Companies</h5> 
</div>
```

Using php echo function to print output.

Comment: how to fetch data from backend folder to frontend is the question